# Is there a way to curl a file with spaces in its name *from IBM object storage (cleversafe)*?

Tags: curl, object-storage, ibm-cloud-platform

I'm using IBM Cloud Object Storage S3 API to connect to IBM object storage. I can curl files with no spaces in their names. Is there a way to curl a file with spaces in its name from IBM object storage (cleversafe)? When I enclose the url in the curl in quotes with verbose turned on, it says HTTP/1.1 400 Illegal character SPACE=' '. When I replace the space in the filename with %20 or %2B or +, the verbose curl says HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.

I can see the file in object storage using the application Cyberduck, but I can't figure out to how to curl it using the IBM S3 API.